# Метод класса по умолчанию

Tags: c#

В Delphi, VB есть методы и/или свойства по умолчанию. В C# я нашел только обращение к элементам массива через свойства по умолчанию:

```
public class Skyscraper
{
  Story[] stories;
  public Story this [int index]
  {
     get { return stories [index]; }
     set
     {
       if (value != null)
         stories [index] = value;
     }
  }
  ...
}

...

Skyscraper empireState = new Skyscraper (...);
empireState[102] = new Story ("The Top One", ...);
```

Можно ли объявить произвольный метод (или хотя бы свойство), к которому можно было бы обращаться так же?
Например, так (код естественно не рабочий, но примерно описывающий, что нужно):

```
public class Skyscraper
{
  Story[] stories;
  public default Story {
     get { return storie; }
     set { storie = value; }
  }
  ...
}

....

Skyscraper empireState = new Skyscraper (...);
empireState = "The Top One";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Skyscraper
{
   public static implicit operator Skyscraper(string str) 
   {
      var skyScraper = new Skyscraper(...);
      skyScraper[102] = new Story (str, ...);
      return skyScraper;
   }
}
...
Skyscraper empireState = new Skyscraper (...);
empireState = "The Top One";
```

- [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)